# Converting NSData to NSString in NSURLConnection = null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

I'm sending data to the server and it is responding to my request and I'm getting a text as shown below in the web... Where would be my issue in  `NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` it is not responding to my NSData while there is data in `responseData`.

My response message:

`{ret:0,msg:"<B>Your request has submitted</B><br/>Your request number is 123 <br/>Have a nice day.<br/>"}`

My code:

```
    NSString *link = @"http://example.jsp";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"first_name=%@&last_name=%@&phone=%@", link, nameField.text, surnameField.text, phoneField.text]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);

NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Finish %@", newStr); // newStr is null!!

UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                  message:newStr
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
[message show];
```

Comment: can u show ur "url" result

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik http://example.com/on/form.jsp?first_name=test1&last_name=test2&phone=34252252345 but it will not help.

Comment: your url is invalid , thats y u r not get the answer, but coding is fine, no problem in ur code, just check ur url is valid or not

Comment: I've checked from the server and I'm entering through the web fine. NSData looks like that <0d0a0d0a 0d0a0d0a 0d0a0d0a 0d0a0d0a 0d0a0d0a 7b726574 3a302c6d 73673a22 3c423e59......> but when I convert it I get null. @Anbu.Karthik I'm sorry I can't share the link

Comment: i tried your code you are passing the invalid url for request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `url` variable is likely already `nil` since your string (`first_name=…`) is not a valid URL: it doesn't even have a scheme and no host.

I bet if you look closely, Xcode is showing a warning that your format has three placeholders (`%@`) but you're passing four arguments. What you probably really want to do is something like;

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?first_name=%@&last_name=%@&phone=%@", link, nameField.text, surnameField.text, phoneField.text]
```

(Note the additional `%@?` at the start.)

In a comment you mention that you do receive data (so your code is just a dummy?). If your call `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` returns `nil` it means your `responseData` is something that is not UTF-8 (which is quite a feat, I have never seen that method fail; I did get garbage back, but never `nil`). The part you're citing looks pretty normal, though: it decodes to `\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n{ret:0,msg:"<B>Y`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I just took a shot part of my link actually it is very long thats why it looks wrong. Normally I can see in the server it is working fine. NSData is getting the data but I can't convert it to NSSting.

Comment: @CAN: Double-check the sent data (for example by writing the data to a file or by doing a network trace). It's most likely not valid UTF-8.

Comment: Yeah it is woking now after I changed the encoding to `NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding` . But there is a big empty space in the middle

Answer (score -1):

Did you alloc responseData ?
you can do it by using delegates

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

and in

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
  NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSLog(@"Finish %@", newStr); // newStr is null!!

UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                              message:newStr
                                             delegate:self
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
[message show];
 }
```

Comment: `responseData` is the return value of his call to `+[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]`. The delegate calls you're citing are only used for _asynchronous_ connections.